# Search for a specific term in a Lucene index

Tags: java, database, lucene

I'm trying to conduct a search on a Lucene index with some specific words that I know are indexed but the result is not very good.

How do I perform a query to a specific term ("129202")? I've tried adding the plus sign at the beginning of the string but it did not work.

My query:

```
QueryParser q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_42, "tags", new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42));
Query query = q.parse("sapatilha feminina ramarim 129202 cinza");
```

Below is a document (xml) indexed that I want to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product>
 <tags>
   <tag>Sapatilha Pedras Preto</tag>
   <tag>ramarin</tag>
   <tag>ramarin 129202</tag>
   <tag>preto</tag>
 </tags>
 <id>71</id>
 <url>http://www.dafiti.com.br/Sapatilha-Pedras-Preto-1135428.html</url>
</product>
```

Comment: " the result is not very good" -- you need to be more specific than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SimpleAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/SimpleAnalyzer.html), the analyzer you are using to query (and I assume to index), uses a [LetterTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/LetterTokenizer.html), which, according to documentation:

> ...defines tokens as maximal strings of adjacent letters, as defined by java.lang.Character.isLetter()

Which is to say, not numbers.  Numbers will be lost entirely by this analyzer.  I recommend you look into a different one, such as [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) or [WhitespaceAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html).

---

To demonstrate:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader("ramarim 129202 cinza");
LetterTokenizer stream = new LetterTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_42, reader);        
stream.setReader(reader);
stream.reset();
while(stream.incrementToken()) {
    System.out.println(stream.reflectAsString(false));
}
stream.close();
```

Outputs:

```
term=ramarim,bytes=[72 61 6d 61 72 69 6d],startOffset=19,endOffset=26
term=cinza,bytes=[63 69 6e 7a 61],startOffset=34,endOffset=39
```

Substituting in `StandardTokenizer` (which is used by `StandardAnalyzer`) will get you:

```
term=ramarim,bytes=[72 61 6d 61 72 69 6d],startOffset=19,endOffset=26,positionIncrement=1,type=<ALPHANUM>
term=129202,bytes=[31 32 39 32 30 32],startOffset=27,endOffset=33,positionIncrement=1,type=<NUM>
term=cinza,bytes=[63 69 6e 7a 61],startOffset=34,endOffset=39,positionIncrement=1,type=<ALPHANUM>
```

Comment: tks... I recreate the index with StandardAnalyzer and it works.